# VBA Save current dated file but delete older files with same name but older date?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my current code:

```
Dim strDestinationFile As String
Dim The_file As String
MyOldName = WHAT CAN I PUT HERE <--
MyNewName = strDestinationFile

Sheets("NAME OF SHEET").Select
Range("I2").Select

The_file = ActiveCell.Value

strDestinationFile = "FILE PATH NAME"
Sheets("NAME OF SHEET").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strDestinationFile
Kill MyOldName
```

Will this work if I enter or designate the correct path and what I want deleted in the "MyOldName = " Section? Basically I have a VBA that same the sheet with the most current date (ie file name: XXXX-10-11-17.xlsm) but I may have previous files of the same beginning name but different date (ie: XXXX-10-10-17) that I want deleted once this one is saved.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You can use DIR() to find the file name using a filter with the file name (sans date). Then you can use DeleteFile method from FileSystemObject library to delete the file.

Comment: Sorry not well versed in VBA, but would you be able to show me in the above code if possible?

Comment: If you spend a couple hours a week watching this series [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) on Youtube, you quickly be able to do some amazing things.

Comment: Not really the intent of this website. SO is a forum to get targeted advice on specific coding errors. It is not a code writing service so you will have to generate your own code. A quick google search gives me this page to understand DIR() https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php and this one shows how to delete files https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/delete-files-folder/#bm2a. Once you have created something you can edit your post with your code and someone will gladly help you on any errors you can't resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Reference:[MSDN Dir() Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx)

Here is a basic Dir() search with pattern matching.

```
Const RootDir As String = "C:\Reports\"
Dim MyFile, MyPath, MyName As String

MyFile = Dir(RootDir & "*??-??-??.xlsx")

Do While MyFile <> ""
    ' Insert Code
    MyFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Although not a complete answer, it should be enough to get you started.